# Duende Identity Server 4 doesn't redirect back to the React client at the end of sign in workflow

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, duende-identity-server

I'm implementing authentication using **Duende Identity Server** based on **CODE grant type**.
I need Identity Server to issue tokens for my React Client App, I added **react-oidc-context** to the Client App as OpenId Connect client. Also I've configured IS to add a few test users on startup for test purposes and added base UI.
The issue is that when I enter test user's credentials to login form on IS and click Login button I see the name of user I just logged in by at the top of the login page, but IS doesn't redirect me back to the Client App, it just refreshes the login page. I was wondering if you could provide any information regarding the possible solutions or issue's causes. Thank you in advance!

Here is the screenshot of page I see after clicking login button:
[Login page after signing in as a test user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6KYh.png)

Here is my config for Identity Server resources:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "spa",
    ClientName = "React Single Page Application",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret") },
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    ClientUri = "https://localhost:44430",
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44430/fetch-data" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44430" },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequirePkce = false,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "weather",
    },
},
```

Here is my config that I use for connecting to IS on the Client App side:

```
{
    authority: "https://localhost:7123",
    client_id: "spa",
    client_secret: "secret",
    redirect_uri: "https://localhost:44430/fetch-data",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:44430',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'weather',
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
};
```

Also here is config of IS service in the program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.IssuerUri = "https://localhost:7123";

        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
    })
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApisResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(builder.Configuration))
    .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
    .AddAspNetIdentity<AppUser>();
```

To fix the issue I've tried switching all endpoints to use https.
Also I've tried to set up cookie policy in IS porgram.cs, below is config that I added:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None,
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
});
```

### Updated

After some time spent on investigation I've finally came up with solution:
The issue was caused by default implementation of login page model (Pages/Account/Login/Index.cshtml/Index.cshtml.cs).I've injected `SignInManager signInManager` to the page's model and used it as users storage instead of default `TestUserStore`, that fixed the issue.

Comment: I wrote a blog post https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/ about troubleshooting common cookie problems with OIDC. that can be worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It's definitely usefull, but the issue doesn't seem to be related to cookie.